# Member "transfer" not found or not visible

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have two contract that are separately deployed.

**FirstContract.sol**

```
contract FirstContract is ERC721 {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter public _id;
    address payable _admin;

    constructor(address admin) ERC721("Token Name", "TOKEN") {
        _admin = payable(admin);
    }

    function incrementToken() public {
        _id.increment();
    }
}
```

**SecondContract.sol**

```
import "./FirstContract.sol";

contract SecondContract {
    FirstContract firstContract;

    constructor(address _address) {
        firstContract = FirstContract(_address);
    }

    function increment() external {
        firstContract.incrementToken(); 
    }

    function transferValue(uint value) external {
        firstContract._admin.transfer(value); // error here
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function () view external returns (address payable).

I'm not sure why this error occurs because the function is marked `public` [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/4c8642b70aadbac89e2b5a55f49890cd4281546e/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L113).

Comment: it is because it's marked internal. To go around it, create a public function in `FirstContract` that calls `_id.increment()` it will work because FirstContract is using Counter

Comment: @egjlmn1 Thank you. I was able to solve it, but ran into another issue. I've updated the question.

Comment: You can make an additional proxy method in FirstContract and call admin.transfer through it - as it is done for incrementToken

Comment: I suspect that it is because _admin is not public. besides that `transfer` is not recommended to send ether. try switching to `call()` look here https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstContract` derives from `ERC721` but your link at the end of the question points at `ERC20` contract. So the definition of `transfer()` in the `ERC20` is not relevant in this context.

---

```
firstContract._admin.transfer(value);
```

This snippet is attempting to use the Solidity native `transfer()` [member](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html#members-of-addresses) of the `address payable` type, i.e. transfer ETH (not an ERC20 token). But it's failing because the `firstContract._admin` is not visible.

It would be visible if the `FirstContract` was a parent of `SecondContract`, as well as if the `_admin` had `public` visibility modifier. Since it doesn't have any visibility modifier specified, the default value `internal` is used.

1. Give the `_admin` property the `public` visibility modifier

```
address payable public _admin;
```

Then you need to change the call of `firstContract._admin` (property) to `firstContract._admin()` (function) because of the way that the compiler handles public properties in external contracts. See more about autogenerated getter functions in the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html#getter-functions).

2. Change the call from the property to the function

```
firstContract._admin().transfer(value);
```

---

Mind that the `SecondContract` doesn't hold any ETH and currently has no way to receive any. So if you were trying to `transfer()` more than the current balance of the `SecondContract` (which is 0), the transaction would revert.

For testing purposes, you can add the `payable` modifier to the constructor and send it some ETH with the deployment transaction, so that you can test the `transferValue()`.

```
constructor(address _address) payable {
```

Comment: Wow thank you this makes perfect sense. So in this case `firstContract._admin().transfer(value);` the compiler is calling two functions? First the getter function and then the transfer function using the returned value of the first function?

Comment: @Kevvv Exactly. Just to be specific - the `transfer()` in your case is a member function of the `address payable` type, so it transfers ETH. It's not related to the `ERC20` `transfer()` function.